# Compute $(a_n,a_{n+1}) \forall n$ with $a_n$ the fibonacci sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here my attempt: Employ the euclidean algorithm, i.e. $\forall r_0,r_1 \exists q,b: r_0 = q\cdot r_1+r_2, 0\le r_2 \lt r_1$. $q,b$ are determined uniquely. Since the definition of the fibonacci sequence is $a_{n+1} = a_n+a_{n-1}$ I can set $r_0 = a_{n+1},r_1 = a_{n},r_2 = a_{n-1}$ with $q=1$. Since the euclidean algorithm will always mimic the definition of the elements of the sequence, $q=1 \forall n$. This proves the assumption. Whos with me?

Comment: $$(F_{n+1},F_n) = (F_n+F_{n-1},F_n) = (F_n,F_{n-1})=\ldots=(F_1,F_2)=1.$$

Comment: That certainly is less verbose! Thanks for the insight. If you write it as an answer, I can give you the check.

Answer (score 1):

To close the question I'd like to leave this here:

$(F_{n+1},F_n) = (F_n+F_{n-1},F_n) = (F_n,F_{n-1})=\ldots=(F_1,F_2)=1$